# How to replace duplicated IDs with a new id?

Tags: mysql

Say I have this table:

```
ID | Name
1  | Daniel
2  | Michael
1  | Lawrence
```

How can I via query find all the duplicated IDs and replace the other one with a new unique number, so that there are no longer duplicates?

Comment: You could just drop the id column altogether, and then recreate it as an autoincrementing primary key

Comment: I know..but the actual IDs in my database are something along 23894712390 and they are used for URL links. By using 1,2,3,4 the links of my URLs look ugly.

Comment: So set the column as BIGINT and the initial AI to 2147483647 - or whatever

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to drop the id column and re add the column as primary key autoincrement:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP idColumnName;
```

and than

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD idColumnNameint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without affecting the ones that aren't duplicated? The IDs are used for links, and some of the links have already been shared around the internet and I don't want them affected.